# How to make C# Solution seed method (not EF)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have method which read config and connection strings from web.config (app.config), but I forget to create particular strings in config. Is it any way to create seed method, or something like bootstraper for project? I guess it should be something like package-manager console commandlets

**UPDATE**

```
PS>Solution-Seed
```

And Class in each project like that:

```
public class ProjectSeed {
    public static Seed() {
        var config = new Config();
        config.Initialize();
   }
}

public class Config{
    public Initialize(){
        Utils.CrateConnectionStringsFromConfigIfNoExists();
     }
}
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [Visual Studio project template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)

Comment: No. Let me make it clear. I have config class, which get settings by property name https://gist.github.com/iamkarlson/461dd08483d9476078d99c7b1cf7169e
    And I just add new property in my impl and config populates automaticaly. But usually I forget to add settings to config. And I want to just "Update-Config" or something like that